# Symfony The security component does not remember session

Tags: symfony-security, symfony-4.3

I use Symfony 4.3.2 on PHP 7.3.4
Here is my security.yaml

```
security:
providers:
    admin_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Admin
            property: username
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_provider, admin_provider]
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    backoffice:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: admin_provider
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            path: admin.logout
            target: admin.login
        form_login:
            login_path: admin.login
            check_path: admin.login
            default_target_path: admin.index
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: user_provider
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: login
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/mon-compte, roles: ROLE_USER }
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto
        cost: 12
    App\Entity\Admin:
        algorithm: auto
        cost: 12
```

I, of course, have the form, the controllers and the views.

Now what happens is:

- When going to /admin i'm getting redirected to /admin/ form
- I successfully authenticate and get taken back to /admin/login.
- There, security decides to ignore my authentication and create a new anonymous session
- It's same problem with /login after authenticate, I back to / in anonymous

I checked my Request in profiler, when POST on my form, I can see Session "_security_main" with my User session.

`C:74:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":294:{a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;s:4:"main";i:2;a:5:{i:0;C:15:"App\Entity\User":29:{a:2:{i:0;i:8;i:1;s:4:"test";}}i:1;b:1;i:2;a:1:{i:0;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":1:{s:47:"\x00Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role\x00role";s:13:"ROLE_CUSTOMER";}}i:3;a:0:{}i:4;a:1:{i:0;s:13:"ROLE_CUSTOMER";}}}}"`

But on my old Symfony project 3.4, I successfully authenticate and get my admin session..

I don't understood why on my new version it doesn't work..
Maybe session lifetime ? session's right writable  ?

The only solution that works is to tick the box "Remember Me"

Thank to help me

Comment: I realize that as soon as I remove {path: ^ / my-account, roles: ROLE_USER}, everything works .. I will see later when I will have my controller User creates